# I want to create only one Tkinter Radiobutton with two options: one click = select another click = unselected. How can I do this?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, radio-button

```
Radiobutton(register_win, variable=var, value=1, bg="#a1c4cc", activebackground="#a1c4cc").place(x=15, y=249)
```

In this code I can select but I can not unselect

Comment: You probably need two radiobuttons, maybe what your looking for is `Checkbutton`.

Comment: Agree with @CoolCloud With a radio button, at least one will remain selected.

Comment: Radiobuttons aren't really the right choice here. They are designed for an exclusive (1 of many) choice, not a toggle. A Checkbutton would be a better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, radio buttons will remain checked unless another radio button in the group is selected.
The below example show how to use radio buttons and check buttons.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
v = tk.IntVar()
v.set(0)

w = tk.IntVar()
w.set(1)

rbtn1 = tk.Radiobutton(root,text="On",variable=v,value=1)
rbtn1.grid()
rbtn2 = tk.Radiobutton(root,text="Off",variable=v,value=0)
rbtn2.grid()

chkbtn = tk.Checkbutton(root,text="Press Me",variable=w)
chkbtn.grid()


root.mainloop()
```

Note that I set the Checkbutton to be checked when the program starts by setting the variable `w` to 1.